# Does this PHP constant exists?

Tags: php, constants

Is there a PHP constant that automatically deletes `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` from `__FILE__`?

So that if Document root is:

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs
```

And `__FILE__` is:

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Project/application/controllers/index.php
```

It returns:

```
/Project/application/controllers/index.php
```

Comment: Did you try inspecting the output of `var_dump($_SERVER)`? This is the first step in basic debugging and learning to help yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want [`_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`](http://php.net/manual/reserved.variables.server.php) or [`_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`](http://php.net/manual/reserved.variables.server.php).

- `PHP_SELF`: The filename of the currently executing script, relative to the document root.
- `SCRIPT_NAME`: Contains the current script's path. This is useful for pages which need to point to themselves. The `__FILE__` constant contains the full path and filename of the current (i.e. included) file.

About the difference between the two:

> However, I just noticed a post on the php.general newsgroup where somebody asked what the difference was between them. Semantically, there isn't any; they should contain the same information. However, historically and technically speaking, there is. SCRIPT_NAME is defined in the CGI 1.1 specification, and is thus a standard. However, not all web servers actually implement it, and thus it isn't necessarily portable. PHP_SELF, on the other hand, is implemented directly by PHP, and as long as you're programming in PHP, will always be present.

Via: http://mwop.net/blog/45-PHP_SELF-versus-SCRIPT_NAME

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could use

```
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
```

I don't know if I understood the question correctly, you could also concat the root and file

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$path_parts = pathinfo('/www/htdocs/inc/lib.inc.php');

echo $path_parts['dirname'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['basename'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['extension'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['filename'], "\n"; // since PHP 5.2.0
?>
```

Comment: And how is this going to help?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such a predefined variable.

But you can easily get it from these two, using as basic string manipulation functions, as `strlen()` and `substr()`